# How do I bind shifted keys to LaTeX-math-mode?

Tags: emacs, auctex

With AUCTeX I can add

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-math-list '(
    (?c "cong " nil)))
```

to my .emacs to make the minor mode [LaTeX-math-mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/auctex/Mathematics.html) spit out `\cong` when it's triggered and I enter <kbd>c</kbd>.

I want it to be invoked with <kbd>C-c</kbd> instead of <kbd>c</kbd> but changing the code to

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-math-list '(
    (?C-c "cong " nil)))
```

gives me "Invalid read syntax: ?" when loading emacs. How do I make this work with <kbd>C-c</kbd> (or any other shifted binding such as <kbd>M-c</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-c</kbd>)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?c` atom is Emacs way of indicating the single character `c`. To use this syntax for control characters, you need to use `?\C-c`. Note that `C-c` is a standard prefix key in Emacs, so using this particular key in `LaTeX-math-list` may cause some conflicts. To use meta instead, you can use `?\M-c`

Details are in the [Elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html).

You can also use `v` as a prefix key, if you define your shortcut as `"v c"` for `vc`, for example.

Comment: How would I got about if I want to bind `C-0` or `v C-0`? Also, math-mode-trigger + `C-c` is already used by AUCTeX so I guess conflicts are not to worry about, see e.g. http://www.stud.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/Hilfe/refcards/tex.pdf

Comment: `?\C-0` for the first - just prefix whatever key you want to use with `?\C-`. There may be some combinations that are unavailable - check the manual page I linked. I don't think you can do shortcuts that require multiple key presses with this syntax - you'd have to write your own wrapper function I think, but I don't use LaTeX-math-mode so I don't know the details.

Comment: When I try `?\C-0`, e.g. `(?\C-0 "lequiv "  nil)`, I get not warning when I start emacs but it seems my .emacs is not loaded and when opening a .tex file it's not automatically opened in AUCTeX but in fundamental mode. There are multiple key presses shortcuts per default in, e.g. math-mode-trigger + `v p` to produce `\varpi`.

Comment: I can't find any documentation, but it looks like if you can use a combination of keys, as long as the first one is v. So to bind `vc`, you would use the syntax `"v c"` as the first element of your definition. I'm not sure why `?\C-0` doesn't work, but it looks like it returns an unusably high integer value.

Comment: Nooo M-c is capitalize-word and is a very useful command, specially in tex mode

Comment: You can bind whatever keys you want, I just explained how. Note that we're talking about tex-math-mode, which only grabs keys under certain circumstances and is unlikely to clash with capitalize word.